# Stellaris LM4F120 Series: What happened to it?

Tags: stellaris, texas-instruments

A while ago I got a Stellaris Launchpad for the new LM4F120 MCU but did not get around to trying it out.

When I now tried accessing any information on the LM4F120 series at TI, anything related to it seems to have disappeared and old links are redirected to the TM4C123 series. I can not even find any datasheets.

What happened? What are the differences to the TM4C123 series? At first glance there does not seem to be any difference.

Comment: As far as I can see, they decided to re-brand the series. New micrcontrollers do have some differences. For example, the new Launchpad should have USB On-the-Go and if I remember correctly some new motor control stuff.

Comment: The mad rush and shoddy way in which the Tiva C replaced the Stellaris reminds me of those weddings which are driven by "oops" circumstances. A lot of people in the community are disappointed with TI about this.

Answer (score 7):

The Stellaris LM4F120 LaunchPad is still available at the [Texas Instruments eStore](https://estore.ti.com/Stellaris-LaunchPad.aspx), but not for long. It is in the process of being replaced by the rebranded "*Tiva C*" series.

The user manual for the LM4F120 Launchpad evaluation board is [still available](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu289a/spmu289a.pdf), as is the [StellarisWare software](http://www.ti.com/tool/sw-ek-lm4f120xl). However, the datasheets for the LM4F120 ARM processors have vanished from the site. The new TM4C123 replacements are apparently not identical.

The new Tiva C LaunchPad is [available for pre-order](https://estore.ti.com/Tiva-C-LaunchPad.aspx), with 8 to 10 weeks to delivery.

This is probably one of the worst-orchestrated product phase-out / replacement exercises Texas Instruments has ever done - Even the shakiest manufacturers rarely remove the datasheets and other documentation for discontinued or replaced products, and TI has typically been pretty dependable.

Answer (score 2):

"Stellaris LM4F120" has been renamed as "Tiva TM4C1233H6PM" (otherwise they are identical and PCB & SW interchangeable)

All TI Stellaris datasheets and product pages have been removed (!!!). This move is so unbelievable that I surely won't be relying on TI MCUs anytime soon.

See [here for a very good reference from TI itself](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/f/908/p/258137/917162.aspx#917162) *(and very juicy customer opinions on this).*